# How do you change the versionCode and the versionName in AndroidManifest with python?

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, character-encoding, android-manifest

I'm trying to set the versionCode and the versionName before building/signing the apk. The building and signing are run without errors.

The problem is that when i try to start the app it crashed and i got `NoClassDefFoundError` found and allot of warnings about Unknown permissions.

If i open the project in eclipse with out changing any thing in AndroidManifest.xml and run the "export sign application package". I got the same error.

If i add a space, remove it, and save the AndroidManifest.xml the application is run without a problem.

This will lead me at least to that this is a encoding problem. Below is the code i use to change the version with.

```
fh,abs_path = mkstemp()
file_path = 'AndroidManifest.xml'
old_file = open(file_path)
new_file = open(abs_path,'w')
for line in old_file:
    line = re.sub(r'android:versionCode=".*?"','android:versionCode="%s"' %    version_code,line)
    line = re.sub(r'android:versionName=".*?"','android:versionName="%s"' % version_name,line)
    new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
close(fh)
old_file.close()
remove(file_path)
move(abs_path, file_path)
```

I have also tried to do this to enforce utf-8. I'm not sure what encoding the manifest should have.

```
line = re.sub(r'android:versionCode=".*?"',u'android:versionCode="%s"' %    version_code,line)
line = re.sub(r'android:versionName=".*?"',u'android:versionName="%s"' % version_name,line)
new_file.write(line.encode('utf-8'))
```

I have tried to check the encoding like this but it got the same errors.

```
file -bi AndroidManifest.xml 
application/xml; charset=us-ascii
```

Do any one have some idea how to fix this?

Comment: The problem may be with line endings, try reading file in "rb" mode and writing `new_file = open(abs_path,'wb')`

Comment: It seams that orignal is LF and my python script writes CRLF. I'm going to test your solution.

Comment: By the way: Because the attributes appear only once in the file, you could also just load the file as a whole in memory, do the replacement and write it out at once

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Android manifest want LF as new line just as Michael Butscher said. To enforce this i had to use `io.open` and sett new line to `'\n'`. I think this is an bug in Android and that Google should fix it so AndroidManifest.xml supports all common types of newline chars.

```
fh,abs_path = mkstemp()
file_path = 'AndroidManifest.xml'

old_file = open(file_path, 'r')
new_file = io.open(abs_path,mode='w', newline='\n')

for line in old_file:
        line = re.sub(r'android:versionCode=".*?"','android:versionCode="%s"' % version_code,line)
        line = re.sub(r'android:versionName=".*?"','android:versionName="%s"' % version_name,line)
        new_file.write(line.decode('utf-8'))

new_file.close()
close(fh)
old_file.close()
remove(file_path)
move(abs_path, file_path)
```